# Declaration troubles about X11 Graphics libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, x11

I'm trying to use on my Linux Mint Debian ,but the gcc compiler show me the only follow mistakes:

```
showme.c|| undefined reference to `XMapWindow'|

showme.c|| undefined reference to `XGetGeometry'|

showme.c|| undefined reference to `XFillRectangle'|

showme.c|| undefined reference to `XDrawString'|

showme.c|| undefined reference to `XClearWindow'|
```

On the header I had declared first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
```

On linux mint Debian I had installed xorg packages.

I don't know what is the problem. Please Help me.

Thanks for all.

Regards.

Comment: It's a linker error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

Undefined reference is a link error. You probably need to link to the X11 library -- try adding `-lX11` to your gcc command.

Comment: Thanks Markku K., your explanation was the solution to my trouble.